# Hide Top-Right Username on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ide

Visual Studio 2015 display the licensed user name on top-right corner of the window.

[image: User name display here]

How do I to hide/remove this? Its really boring blur it whenever I need take screenshots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have [an extension](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/extensions.html#hide_sign_in) for Visual Commander that hides it on Visual Studio startup:

```
private bool HideSignIn()
{
    System.Windows.FrameworkElement e = 
        FindElement(System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow, 
            "PART_MenuBarFrameControlContainer");
    if (e != null)
    {
        e.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Formidable! Thank you!